# Is there a difference between $y=\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ and $y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$

Tags: calculus

Is there a difference between $$y=\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$ and $$y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$$
If there is a difference, why when I give the square for both equations, they will be equal.

Comment: Not if all quantities are positive, i.e. $-1<x\le 1$.

Comment: @Reery. You get it equal after squaring because $1\neq-1$, but $1^2=(-1)^2$.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. There are differences. In the region where both of $x-1$ and $x+1$ are negative, the upper one will be wrong and lower one is correct. This region is $(-\infty, -1).$

For complex numbers there are no difference because any number is acceptable under the sqrt (positive or negative)

Comment: You proved that there is no difference on interval $(-1,\infty)$, but what about complex numbers? For which complex numbers $x$ there is no difference?

Answer (score -1):

In general for real numbers, $ sqrt(\dfrac{a}{b}) = \dfrac{sqrt(|a|)}{sqrt(
|b|)} $ for $ (a \wedge b) \epsilon \mathbb{R}$

Comment: No, $a = -1$, $b=1$

Comment: if this were the case, then you would have $sqrt(-1)$ which is not a member of the set of real numbers. if $a = -2, b = -3$ you would then have $sqrt(\dfrac{2}{3})$ but, that is not equal to $\dfrac{sqrt(-2)}{sqrt(-3)}$

Comment: @DanielV That is the purpose of the absolute value